# Manipulação de dados de diferentes estruturas na mesma tabela com Dplyr R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

Preciso extrair da pasta de clientes os dados, em formato de tabela. Na imagem 1, coloquei a aba de interesse do arquivo xlms, da pasta dos clientes, deixei destacado em vermelho.[image: Imagem_1]

Na imagem 2, destaquei em vermelho todas os dados de interesse, não é todos os dados disponíveis no ficheiro.
[image: Imagem_2]

O formato que preciso criar é o seguinte:

> ```
>   Nome do Cliente   CNPJ    VENDAS   etc...
>   AAAAAAAAAAA     11.111.111/0001-11   2020 ...
>   AAAAAAAAAAA     11.111.111/0001-11   2021 ...
>   AAAAAAAAAAA     11.111.111/0001-11   2022 ...
>   AAAAAAAAAAA     11.111.111/0001-11   2023 ...
>   BBBBBBBBBBB     22.222.222/0002-22   2020 ...
>   BBBBBBBBBBB     22.222.222/0002-22   2021 ...
>   BBBBBBBBBBB     22.222.222/0002-22   2022 ...
>   BBBBBBBBBBB     22.222.222/0002-22   2023 ...
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apesar dos votos para baixo da pergunta, aqui vai uma solução em R base.
A primeira e principal função é a mais comprida mas na verdade é muito simples. Depois de dividir as linhas da entrada por espaços com `strsplit` extrai as colunas dos dados uma a uma. A segunda função tem como argumentos o padrão dos ficheiros e o diretório e obtém primeiro os nomes dos ficheiros com `list.files`, lê os dados com `readLines` e depois chama a função principal para processar cada um dos conjuntos de dados.

```
parse_form <- function(x, header) {
  # eliminar linhas em branco
  ok <- (sapply(x, nchar) > 0L)
  x <- x[ok]
  # separar o texto de cada linha pelos espaços
  lines_list <- strsplit(x, " +")
  # e eliminar as strings vazias
  lines_list <- lapply(lines_list, \(x) x[nchar(x) > 0L])
  lines_list <- lapply(lines_list, trimws)
  #
  # agora processar as linhas uma a uma
  # como o formato é fixo e conhecido de antemão
  # não vale a pena complicar o código
  #
  Nome_Cliente <- lines_list[[1L]][2L]
  CNPJ <- lines_list[[1L]][4L]
  VENDAS <- lines_list[[2L]][-1L] |> as.integer()
  PRODUTO_A_EM_KBRL <- lines_list[[3L]][-1L] |> as.integer()
  PRODUTO_B_EM_KBRL <- lines_list[[4L]][-1L] |> as.integer()
  data <- lines_list[[5L]][-1L] |> as.Date("%d/%m/%Y")
  `Fat Líquido` <- lines_list[[6L]][-(1:2)] |> as.integer()
  Resultado <- lines_list[[7L]][-1L] |> as.integer()
  # juntar tudo num df
  y <- data.frame(VENDAS, PRODUTO_A_EM_KBRL, PRODUTO_B_EM_KBRL,
                  data, `Fat Líquido`, Resultado, check.names = FALSE)
  # estes dois só têm um valor cada
  y$Nome_Cliente <- Nome_Cliente
  y$CNPJ <- CNPJ
  # e sair com a ordem requerida
  y[c(7:8, 1:6)]
}
processar_formularios <- function(pattern, path = ".") {
  fl_list <- list.files(path = path, pattern = pattern, full.names = TRUE)
  form_list <- lapply(fl_list, readLines)
  form_list <- lapply(form_list, parse_form)
  do.call(rbind, form_list)
}

processar_formularios("so_pt_589327.txt")
# Nome_Cliente               CNPJ VENDAS PRODUTO_A_EM_KBRL PRODUTO_B_EM_KBRL         data Fat Líquido Resultado
# 1  AAAAAAAAAAA 11.111.111/0001-11   2020                 0                 1 2019-12-31      606949     17401
# 2  AAAAAAAAAAA 11.111.111/0001-11   2021                 0                 2 2020-12-31      739963     25615
# 3  AAAAAAAAAAA 11.111.111/0001-11   2022                 0                 3 2021-12-31     1087192     88542
# 4  AAAAAAAAAAA 11.111.111/0001-11   2023                 0                 4 2022-12-31     1263516     65477
```

Comment: O pessoal da tag r anda agressivo nos downvotes ultimamente.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Rui Barradas. Pois é Marcus Nunes, tá cada vez mais difícil de pedir uma ajuda aqui para o pessoal do tag r. Cada vez menos estou utilizando este canal, vendo que o pessoal não tem muito interesse em ajudar. Acho que o pessoal aqui nasce sabendo.

Comment: Tem acontecido bastante na tag python também.

Comment: Rui Barradas. Fui reproduzir aqui no meu relatório, só que o negócio é muito mais complexo que eu imaginava.  O meu list. Files que busco são arquivos formato xlsm. E para extrair, eu preciso usar (a principio) o read_excel(sheet = 'PROPOSTA', range = 'A13:I99'), onde eu faço alguns cortes e o sheet não é o primeiro. O formulário que eu criei aqui, ele é só um pedaço, pois o original é bem maior. Porém o teu script está sendo muito proveitoso,  estou aprendendo bastante com ele. Continuando...+

Comment: Eu só não entendi pq tu colocas neste formato lines_list[[4L]][-1L], com valor negativo. Reproduzindo o meu, vi  que não tem nenhum da lista com valor, por exemplo lines_list[[1L]][4L],  saiu tudo com a segunda parte [1].  O exemplo de VENDAS os anos localizei assim: [[52]][1] "2020", [[102]][1] "2021", [[152]][1] "2022", [[202]][1] "2023". Como ficaria esta linha? VENDAS <- lines_list[[2L]][-1L] |> as.integer(). Acredito que tu me mostrando esta linha, eu conseguiria reproduzir nas outras. Obrigado

Comment: @EvertonToledo A função `parse_form` parte do princípio que tens os dados tal e qual como na pergunta, só um `Nome_Cliente` por ficheiro. Nesse caso o vetor `lines_list[[4L]]` inclui tudo dessa linha. Na linha nº 4 temos o descritivo `"PRODUTO_B_EM_KBRL"` seguido dos dados numéricos. O índice negativo remove o primeiro elemento do vetor e ficam só os dados. O mesmo para as outras linhas.

Comment: @EvertonToledo Se há mais de um `Nome_Cliente` por ficheiro por favor edita a pergunta com um exemplo mais representativo do problema, mais representativo dos ficheiros.

Comment: Obrigado @RuiBarrabas pela ajuda. Eu tentei reproduzir um ficheiro mais resumido, mas acredito não ter feito isso muito bem. o Ficheiro é um cliente só. Vou editar a pergunta, colocando uma foto ficheiro, olhando o arquivo excel, tvz fique melhor de entender.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, consegui criar uma extração destes dados. Muito obrigado pela tua ajuda. Tu me deu a luz de como extrair. Abs